# IsomorphicGraphQ fails to recognize that two empty graphs are identical

Tags: graphs-and-networks, bugs, expression-test

**Bug introduced in 9.0.1 or earlier and fixed in 11.0.1**

---

Consider the following two graphs:

```
g1 = Graph[{1, 2, 3}, {}];

g2 = SimpleGraph@Graph[{1, 2, 3}, {1 <-> 1}];
```

They are clearly the same thing because `SimpleGraph` will remove the self loop (only edge) from `g2`.

Yet `IsomorphicGraphQ` disagrees:

```
IsomorphicGraphQ[g1, g2]

(* False *)
```

I believe this is a bug and it exists in all of 9.0.1 through to 10.4.0.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Given the example of `Compress`/`Uncompress` I agree that this is a bug and I added that tag accordingly.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, given your geo, any chance you can be in Pasadena early Aug for a day? ... Szabolcs, I'd extend the same invite but you're a bit further @ away this time.

Comment: @alancalvitti I don't think that will be possible but I must say I am curious why you ask.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, you already know why: software is eating the world and M.SE is a global lever. Take a look at some of the tech in this useful fiction like Ghost Fleet >> http://bit.ly/1e7MJ38. If you like it I'll msg you a 2-part key w/ info.

Comment: @alancalvitti is this poetry?

Comment: @shrx, was motivation to get him down to a WR meeting at Caltech to discuss tech trends.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A simple workaround is to re-build the graph object by cycling it through some other representation.  Here are two possible solutions:

```
rebuildGraph[g_] := Uncompress@Compress[g] (* solution 1 *)
rebuildGraph[g_] := Graph[VertexList[g], EdgeList[g]] (* solution 2 destroys properties but it's fine for isomorphism testing purposes *)

isomorphicGraphQ[g1_, g2_] := 
 IsomorphicGraphQ[rebuildGraph[g1], rebuildGraph[g2]]
```

Now this gives a correct result:

```
isomorphicGraphQ[g1, g2]
(* True *)
```