# Trying to remove duplicate isomorphic graphs in a list of graphs

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am working on a *Mathematica* program that involves taking a graph and generating all of its single-edge contractions.

When I get this list of contractions, it often happens that many of the graphs in the list are isomorphic. I am wondering if there is a way for *Mathematica* to throw out all of the extra graphs in my list that are isomorphic duplicates.

Additionally, I need to be able to take two lists of graphs and test to see if the two lists have any isomorphic graphs in common. I think I will run into the same problem here, where *Mathematica* thinks that graphs with differently named vertices are different when they are really isomorphic.

#### Edit

I just want to add that I am very new to *Mathematica*. I am aware of the `GraphIsomorphismQ` function but I am not sure how to use it for the purposes described above.

I have tried the `DeleteDuplicates` function to remove isomorphic graphs from a list, but it did not work.

Comment: Learning Mathematica requires effort (as is the case with almost everything else). Have you tried something? Can you show it?

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the second argument of [`DeleteDuplicates`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteDuplicates.html): it is the function used to test if two elements are the same.

Thus you can use

```
DeleteDuplicates[list, IsomorphicGraphQ]
```

to filter out duplicate graphs.

Be aware of this bug in [`IsomorphicGraphQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IsomorphicGraphQ.html) (and consider complaining to Wolfram about it if it affects you):

- [IsomorphicGraphQ fails to recognize that two empty graphs are identical](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88582/12)