# Wrong results from IsomorphicGraphQ

Tags: bugs, graphs-and-networks

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and fixed in 10.4**

---

How can two graphs with zero edges on four vertices, not be isomorphic? What am I missing?

```
one = Graph[Range[1, 4], {}]
two = EdgeDelete[Graph[Range[1, 4], {1 <-> 2}], {1 <-> 2}]
IsomorphicGraphQ[one, two]
```

This returns `False` under Mathematica 10.1.

Comment: It returns `True` in `11.0.1`

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88582/12  That other problem is also about the failure to consider empty graphs isomorphic, but that one is present in 10.4 as well. Yours is not present in 10.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Anjan Kumar says this works in 11.0.1, this is probably yet another stupid bug in Mathematica's graph handling. The following works correctly in 10.1:

```
IsomorphicGraphQ[one, AdjacencyGraph[AdjacencyMatrix[two]]]
```